# Prometheus + blackbox component -> How to monitoring HTTP content without seperate checks

Tags: prometheus

I have prometheus working with blackbox component, and wish to pass parameters to the blackbox component - Apart from module and target which already work quite well.

I am looking for a way to pass in keys like 'fail_if_not_matches_regexp' and other parameters which can be set in the blackbox component, and for the pass in values to override the existing ones. Do I need to be writing relabel_configs for blackbox component?

Currently I have prometheus passing in key/value pairs to the URL, however I'm not sure what the key should be in the URL.

http://localhost:9115/probe?module=http_2xx&modules_fail_if_not_matches_regexp=1234&target=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com

This leads to the question of which blackbox component variables can I set using the URL key/value pairs?

Also, I could create seperate blackbox configurations which contain the static text and options to check for each target, however I would rather something dynamic which using the discovery JSON file method (which current works for setting target params).

```
    {
      "targets": [ "https://yyy" ],
      "labels": {
        "fail_if_not_matches_regexp": "web services under your control",
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported, create modules in the blackbox exporter for every set of settings you need.